# How to get C code output in to a shell script variable

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc MatrixCPU.c
echo "Enter the matrix size";
read size
total="0"   
 val= $(./a.out $size)
echo $val
```

I want to get C code output for a shell script. What have I missed here?

Comment: remove the space between `val=` and `$(./a.out $size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc MatrixCPU.c
echo "Enter the matrix size";
read size
total="0"   
val=$(./a.out $size)
echo $val
```